# Tabbar With 6 Tabs

Tags: uitabbar

Anyone know of a way to place 6 tabs in the tabbar without the more button kicking in?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You will have to write your own custom one.

Answer (score 0):

as Daniel said you would have to write your own.

I did write an iOS 7+ compatible simple UITabBar+UITabBarController replacement that can support any number of tabs and that uses Auto Layout to build it's view hierarchy. Check out [NGTabBar](http://www.github.com/goles/ngtabbar).